# Apply EventListener to table instead of each cell. How?

Tags: javascript

In the code below it works fine but i apply **EventListener** to each **Cell** in table in for loop instead i would like to apply just one **EventListener** to the table itself to change the `background-color` for selected **Cell**. How i can do that ?

```
let height, width, color, reset;
const error = document.querySelector('#error');
function makeGrid(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    clrGrid();
    height = document.querySelector("#inputHeight").value;
    width = document.querySelector("#inputWidth").value;
    if (height > 50 || width > 50 || height < 1 || width < 1) {
        if (!error.classList.contains("error")) {
            error.classList.toggle("error");
            error.innerText = "the dimension has to be smaller than 50 and bigger than 0";
        }
    } else {
        error.innerText = "";
        error.classList.remove("error");
        for (let x = 0; x < height; x++) {
            const tRow = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas").insertRow(x);

            for (let y = 0; y < width; y++) {
                const tCell = tRow.insertCell(y);
                tCell.addEventListener("click", fillSquare);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Apply Color to Cells
color = document.querySelector('#colorPicker');
function fillSquare () {
    this.setAttribute("style", `background-color: ${color.value}`);
}

// Clear Canvas Grid
canvas = document.querySelector("#pixelCanvas");
function clrGrid() {
    error.innerText = "";
    error.classList.remove("error");
    while (canvas.firstChild){
        canvas.removeChild(canvas.firstChild);
   }
}
```

Comment: Add the listener to the table, then use `function fillSquare(e) { ... }` and grab `e.target` to get the clicked elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the click listener on the table and access the cell using `event.target`.

Bellow you can find little demonstration on how to use it.

```js
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  const target = event.target;
  
  if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
    target.style.background = 'blue';
  }
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Content</td>
    <td>Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation. Set the event listener on the table and then ask whether the event target (element that was the source of the event) is cell `td` element. If it is, then use event target again to modify the cell as you want (in such case `event.target` will be the corresponding cell element).

You can see it here.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
table.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'TD') {
    event.target.style.background = 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

When you click on a cell, its background color will change to red even though there is only on listener assigned to its parent table.

In your case you should remove line

```
tCell.addEventListener("click", fillSquare);
```

change the `fillSquare` function so that it takes argument (element target)

```
function fillSquare (element) {
  element.setAttribute("style", `background-color: ${color.value}`);
}
```

and add event listener to the table like this

```
const table = document.querySelector('select-parent-table');
table.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.nodeName === 'TD') {
    fillSquare(event.target);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you click on the table, first check if it's a td then change the background color to whatever you wish.

```js
const table = document.getElementById("table");

table.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
 const element = e.target;
 if(element.tagName === "TD"){
  element.style.backgroundColor = "red"
 }
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```